# Удаление дубликатов

Tags: sql

Пусть существует таблица *users* с полями *user_id* и *user_name*, и в ней имеются записи с одниковыми значениями *user_name*. Запрос удаления "лишних" строк будет выглядеть, допустим, так:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN
  (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name IN
    (SELECT user_name FROM
      (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt, user_name FROM users GROUP BY user_name HAVING cnt>1) AS t1
    )
  AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users GROUP BY user_name)
  )
```

Или так:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN
  (SELECT t1.user_id FROM
    (SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users) AS t1
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt, MIN(user_id) AS min_id FROM users GROUP BY user_name HAVING cnt > 1) AS t2
  ON t1.user_name=t2.user_name AND t1.user_id!=t2.min_id
  )
```

В общем, как ни крути, получается, по сути, два вложенных селекта, и время работы, по идее, соответственно, в два раза больше, хотя если бы можно было обратиться к результату *t1* после *AND* в первом примере, то было бы более по фэншую, наверно (а так костыли какие-то). Можно ли как-то это исправить?

И второе, почему-то на указанные выше примеры SQLyog ругается:

```
Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause
```

Английский у меня хромает, но, насколько я понял, оно утверждает, что я не могу отправить в команду удаления результат вложенного запроса!? О_о

P.S. Сильно не ругайте, sql не вспоминал ещё со школьных лет...

Comment: > И второе, почему-то на указанные выше примеры SQLyog ругается:

не SQLyog, а сам MySQL. Запросы на обновление данных, включающие подзапросы, работающие с обновляемой таблицей, запрещены. В принципе, можно обмануть MySQL и сделать еще один промежуточный селект-обертку.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/193369/mysql-запрос-sql-на-удаление-дубликатов-из-таблицы-по-одному-полю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Хоть после комментариев это стало и очевидно, на всякий случай напишу здесь работающий с mysql код (с упомянутой селект-обёрткой), может, кому и пригодится:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM users GROUP BY user_name) AS t1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

В надежде, что user_id - первичный ключ:

```
delete from users where user_id not in(
select max(user_id) from users 
group by user_name);
```

Это классика. user_id в запросе можно заменить на rowid, если такая псевдоколонка существует в вашей СУБД.

Comment: Читайте комментарии, если проверять лень. 

> Запросы на обновление данных, включающие подзапросы, работающие с обновляемой таблицей, запрещены.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я таким запросом пользовался многократно.

Comment: MySQL? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04e35

> You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause:

Comment: ссылка на схему с ошибкой не создается. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4338fb
раскомментировать надо запрос.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,нет, не MySQL, а Oracle.

Comment: тогда ваш ответ офтопик. или вы считаете ТС, являясь новичком (судя по вопросам) спрашивал об оракле? И компенсирующий плюс вам поставили такие же внимательные люди. файспалм.